# Is there a way to transport data with a 100% delivery guarantee using RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, eventual-consistency, reliable-message-delivery

I'm building a system in which I'd like to use RabbitMQ as the main message passing mechanism.

My system requires very strong guarantees for message delivery, as in, messages *must* arrive at their destination and acknowledged,
otherwise I expect them to be requeued, and redelievered.

*The use case is maintaining eventual consistency between 2 systems*

**I'd also like to avoid having to manage any state regarding the messages in my application.**

I know that publishing a persistent message does not provide a 100% guarantee that it was persisted to disk, because fsync(2) is not called for every message.

thus, my question is - **Can I use RabbitMQ as a 100% reliable* message passing mechanism?**

I've read about transactions, but couldn't find anything besides a [2011 blogpost](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/) which also doesn't explicitly state that an `fsync(2)` is performed for every message, or that a (synchronous) failure occurs if it doesn't succeed.

<sub>* by reliable I mean that the messages should eventually be delivered, always. duplicate messages are acceptable.</sub>

Comment: I think this is too broad for Stack Overflow. The docs here on [reliable delivery](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html) refer you to the mailing list. My personal opinion is _yes_, RabbitMQ gives you reliable delivery but someone else might cosider x, y or z failure condition as unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Horba, but I feel that this question does deserve an answer, and is not too broad. I’m not talking about general reliability, but instead describe a specific situation in which delivery failures are possible, and request a solution for this specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use RabbitMQ as a 100% reliable message passing mechanism?

Yes, use persistent messages, publisher confirms, and consumer acknowledgements - [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html).

When your publisher receives a confirmation, the message has been written and synced to disk.

Comment: I’ve read about publisher confirms briefly and did not understand that they provide a stronger guarantee than persistent messages on durable queues. This covers most of my concerns, except for managing state in my application. Anyway, I guess you can’t have it all. Thanks!

Comment: Publisher confirms and persistent messages are two separate things. You can have non-persistent messages with publisher confirms, and vice versa. It is the combination of using both that is most reliable. Yes, you can have it all.

Comment: Yes, that is very clear to me. I still have to manage the state of failed messages though - hence I can't, technically, "have it all".